# why is the object "this" not reference to the global window object?

Tags: javascript

The Foo is being executed from the window global object like this:

```
  new Foo();   // false why?
  Foo();       // true

 function Foo()
 { 
     alert(this == window); 
 };
```

But when I run this function Foo code, the alert message says false, why is this when Foo is executed from the global window object?

Comment: `console.log(this)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you used `new`. The `new` operator creates a new object, sets that object's prototype to be Foo.prototype, then invokes Foo with `this` set equal to the newly-created object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Answer (score 1):

It's not in the window context. It's in the function context. If you'd like it to be in the window context, you can do

```
foo.call(window);
```

Comment: Foo();   // true,  new Foo(); // false, what context is it in because "this" is an object..

Comment: @Nora sorry it's getting late in the day. I meant to say it *is* in the function context

Answer (score -2):

JavaScript has function-level scoping. In your example, `this` is referring to the `Foo` function.

Comment: this == Foo // still says false